# Android HttpURLConnect POST Stream Size

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to follow the tutorial here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

to make a post call in android. The issue I am having it I am not sure how to write the post call to the http connection.

```
URL url = new URL("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart");
            HttpURLConnection client = null;
            client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            client.setRequestMethod("POST");

            client.setRequestProperty("cht", "lc");
            client.setRequestProperty("chtt", "This is | my chart");
            client.setRequestProperty("chs", "300x200");
            client.setRequestProperty("chxt", "x");
            client.setRequestProperty("chd", "t:40,20,50,20,100");
            client.setDoOutput(true);
            client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            outputPost.write(client.getRequestProperties().toString().getBytes());
            outputPost.flush();
            outputPost.close();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            Log.d(TAG, "Input" + in.read());
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException error) {
            //Handles an incorrectly entered URL
            Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURL");
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException error) {
//Handles URL access timeout.
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Timeout");
        } catch (IOException error) {
//Handles input and output errors
            Log.d(TAG, "IOexception");
        }
```

The tutorial uses a custom method to write the stream but I still run into writing an unknown number of bytes for the body of the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions to consider:

1. Does the Google chart API require information to be sent via the header variables?
2. Does the Google chart API require information to be sent in the body?
3. Is the information in the body being sent in the correct format?
4. Missing Content-Type header variable
5. Why is the same data being set in the header and body?

After reading the [Google Chart Guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/post_requests) the following code will successfully make a POST request to the Google Chart API and retrieve the image as bytes.

To write the post data see the following line in the `getImage` code sample: `con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);`

Take note of the following line to set the post size: `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));`

```
  public byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Store the post data
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("cht", "lc");
    params.put("chtt", "This is | my chart");
    params.put("chs", "300x200");
    params.put("chxt", "x");
    params.put("chd", "t:40,20,50,20,100");

    // Build the post data into appropriate format
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }

    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    // post the data
    con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
    InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

    // read the data from response
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
    int n;

    while ( (n = inputStream.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
        baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks after I posted that was what I started to consider, building the body of the message separate from the client. Do you know then if you use the .setRequestProperty if that puts the info on the header and is therefore sent when the connection is established with out the use of writing to a stream?

Comment: The info gets sent without writing to the stream but depends on the google api whether it will look for info in the request headers...